# How to increase height of carousel_slider in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

I have a carousel slider with 5 images but I am not able to increase it's height. I want it to take up 70% of my screen. What should I do?

This is the code I've used:

```
List<String> list = [
      'images/image1.png',
      'images/image2.png',
      'images/image3.png',
      'images/image4.png',
      'images/image5.png',
    ];

Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: CarouselSlider(
          options: CarouselOptions(),
          items: list.map((item) => Container(
            child: Image.asset(
              item,
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
            ), 
          )).toList(),
        ),
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
List<String> list = [
      'images/image1.png',
      'images/image2.png',
      'images/image3.png',
      'images/image4.png',
      'images/image5.png',
    ];

Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: CarouselSlider(
          options: CarouselOptions(),
          items: list.map((item) => Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7, 
            child: Image.asset(
              item,
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
              
            ), 
          )).toList(),
        ),
      )
```

Comment: It's cropping the top and bottom part of my image in this solution.